# Which formula works best for my situation?

Tags: excel, time

I have situation here and I am going nuts right now.
In column A, I have 5 cities
In column B, I have the local times of those 5 cities from column A

Now I want the following.
In C1 when I type any of the 5 cities, I want D1 to display the local time of that city.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have a look at the INDEX/MATCH formula.

This is the formula in D1:

```
=INDEX(B1:B5,MATCH(C1,A1:A5,0))
```

The `MATCH` function will lookup the row number of the city from C1 in the range of cities `A1:A5`.

The INDEX function will then pick the time with the corresponding row number in the range of times `B1:B5`.

Be aware that the last parameter in the `MATCH` function should be 0 in order to get exact match.

[image: Example of INDEX/MATCH]

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you. This has solved my case. Thanks a lot!